# Incorrect square wave sampling using scipy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, signal-processing

Trying to plot 2Hz square wave sampled at 4Hz (see attached figure below). Why am I not getting a uniformity for sample encircled red which should IMO be at -1 marked by 2nd red arrow:

[image]

Here is my python code *(assuming ipython shell and imported numpy(as np), scipy(signal) and matplotlib(plt))*

```
t4 = np.linspace(0,4,16,endpoint=False)
s2t4 = signal.square(2.0*np.pi*2.0*t4)
t500 = np.linspace(0,4,500,endpoint=False)
s2t500 = signal.square(2*np.pi*2*t500)
plt.ylim(-2,2); plt.plot(t500,s2t500,'k',t4,s2t4,'b',t4,s2t4,'bo'); plt.show()
```

Comment: My guess would be floating point errors. The point you circled is probably very slightly less than 2.75, so the value is 1. The easiest way to fix this would be sample your triangular wave at the midpoints of the square wave rather than the corners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of normal floating point imprecision.  You are attempting to sample the square wave right at the points where the jumps take place.  This will be sensitive to the imprecision of floating point numbers.

The value you circled is `s2t4[11]`, and `t4[11]` is 2.75.  Take a look:

```
In [15]: signal.square(2.0*np.pi*2.0*t4[11])
Out[15]: array(1.0)
```

Add a tiny amount to the argument, and you get -1:

```
In [16]: signal.square(2.0*np.pi*2.0*t4[11] + 1e-14)
Out[16]: array(-1.0)
```

If you shift `t4` so the samples are away from the discontinuities, it should work fine.